# StoreKit2 based IAP integration with Electron

Tags: swift, electron, in-app-purchase

Currently Electron has inAppPurchase module that is based on the original API. This module doesn't have on-device receipt validation (I understand server-side validation is secure). In addition, the API is also not suitable for subscriptions since the Transaction object doesn't seem to have many subscription related attributes.

StoreKit 2 based in-app-purchases API is much simpler and is Swift based. Most older posts indicate experimental projects trying to integrate Swift with Node. It seems Swift and C++ interoperability has improved since 2022 and so it is unclear to me if it is now a lot more easier to integrate Swift into Node and specifically with Electron.

Does anyone have pointers on how to go about integrating Swift based Store Kit 2 API with an Electron App for in-app purchases?